# ошибка conflicting declaration при иницилизации обекта

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, типы-данных

```
 struct Sizes {
    const int LAYERS;
    const int FIRST_LAYER;
    const int SECOND_LAYER;
    const int THIRD_LAYER;
};

class Test
{
private:
    Sizes sizes;
public:
    Test(Sizes sizes_f):sizes(sizes_f) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<__cplusplus<<std::endl;
    Sizes sizes {3,3,2,1};
    //Parser().parse();
    //Neural(sizes);
    Test(sizes);

}
```

ошибка

```
conflicting declaration «Test sizes»
   35 |  Test(sizes);
      |       ^~~~~
src/Main.cpp:32:8: замечание: предыдущая декларация «Sizes sizes»
   32 |  Sizes sizes {3,3,2,1};
      |        ^~~~~
```

Как исправит? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что вы хотите получить? По сути, вы объявили переменную `sizes` типа `Test`, а так как перед этим уже была объявлена переменная `sizes` типа `Sizes`, то...

Может, вы хотели этого:

```
Test{sizes};
```

?

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я обявил l-value обект типа Test конструктор которого принимает sizes обект типа Sizes. Для простоти пишу аналог` Test objectByTypeTest(sizes);

Comment: А нет ви прави. Наверно не сходство версии. Я подумал "Test{size}"="Test(size)"

Comment: Это не несходство версии. `Test objectByTypeTest(sizes);` без имени переменной  `objectByTypeTest` - это объявление переменной `sizes`. Хотя кто-то, поставивший минус ответу, похоже, так не считает :)

Comment: я не ставил минус, но я уверен исползовал такой тип иницилизации, толко не помну в какои версии

Comment: Для инициализации - запросто поверю. Например, `Test t = Test(sizes);` Но тут-то у вас **нет** никакой инициализации! Что именно вы инициализируете в своем коде, покажите?

Answer (score 0):

Конструкторы вызываются так:

```
Test t = Test(sizes); 
Test t(sizes);        
Test{sizes};
```

А `Test(sizes);` это или вызов функции Test или объявление `Test sizes`